# Defining a metric space

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

I'm studying for actuarial exams, but I always pick up mathematics books because I like to challenge myself and try to learn new branches.  Recently I've bought Topology by D. Kahn and am finding it difficult.  Here is a problem that I think I'm am answering sufficiently but any help would be great if I am off.

If $d$ is a metric on a set $S$, show that 
$$d_1(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$$ is a metric on $S$.

The conditions for being a metric are $d(X,Y)\ge{0}, d(X,Y)=0$ iff $X=Y$, $d(X,Y)=d(Y,X)$, and $d(X,Y)\le{d(X,Z)+d(Z,Y)}$.  Thus, we simply go axiom by axiom.

1)  Since both $d(x,y)\ge{0}$ and $1+d(x,y)\ge{0},$ it is clear that $d_1(x,y)\ge{0}$.  (Is this a sufficient analysis?)
2) $d_1(x,x)=\frac{d(x,x)}{1+d(x,x)}=\frac{0}{1+0}=0$.
3) $d_1(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}=\frac{d(y,x)}{1+d(y,x)}=d_1(y,x).$
4) $d_1(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}\le{\frac{d(x,z)+d(z,y)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}}=\frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}+\frac{d(z,y)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}\lt\frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)}+\frac{d(z,y)}{1+d(z,y)}=d_1(x,z)+d_1(z,y).$

However, #4 is strictly less, not less than or equal to, according to my analysis, so where did I go wrong?

Comment: You meant to ask "show that... *also is a metric distance* ", right?

Comment: If you prove that $a<b$, then you’ve certainly proved that $a\le b$. However, your calculation in (4) is incorrect: how do you justify the claim that $$\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}\le\frac{d(x,z)+d(z,y)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}\;?$$ The numerator on the right is at least as big as the numerator on the left, but the denominators aren’t the same.

Comment: It looks correct: $\frac{a}{1+a} \leq \frac{b}{1+b}$ whenever $0 \leq a \leq b$.

Comment: @LordSoth: Yes, but it still ought to be justified; the justification isn’t hard, but it isn’t one of the obvious inequalities that everyone recognizes right off the bat.

Comment: since $d(x,y)$ is defined itself as a metric, then $d(x,y)\le{d(x,z)+d(z,y)}$, right?  Since d(x,y) is a metric that axiom holds and we can introduce that into the equation?

Comment: Yes, but you still need to use the inequality that @LordSoth mentions in his comment, and it’s not one that’s so obvious as not to require some mention/justification.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes, hopefully the OP knowingly took that step (inequality).

Comment: @LordSoth: It’s certainly possible, and I hope so, but I’ve seen a fair number of students fail to realize that since the denominator may increase, one really does need more than the $\triangle\ne$ in the numerator.

Comment: hmmm....i'm not sure i remember how to justify it!  It seemed obvious when I did it, but now, just substituting some small values, I can see it, but having trouble putting it to paper.

Comment: There is a little slip in 2), the conditon says $d(x,y)=0$ iff (if and only if) $x=y$. You verified only one direction.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I agree, and interestingly, different inequalities are obvious to different people. During paper revisions, sometimes reviewers want me to write why (e.g.) $1+x+2x^3 \leq 2+3x^3 ,\,x\geq 0$. But, at the end, they are right :)

Comment: Your analysis is *almost* perfect for the first condition. Noting that $d(x,y)\ge0$ and that $1+d(x,y)>0$ (we can't let the denominator be $0$, after all) will be enough to conclude that $d_1(x,y)\ge0.$ Also, there's nothing wrong with the inequality being strict in the last bit. However, in general it needn't be. Consider the case that $x=y=z$.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst Use the fact $$ \frac{a}{1 + a} = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + a} $$

Comment: Ahh, I'm still not seeing the inequality...

Comment: @muzzlator, please expound...

Comment: Bravo, for self-learning!  Another great topology book is by James Munkres.  http://goo.gl/zv6vH

Comment: @SammyBlack, It takes a little more time, i find, but i'm fascinated by math and I finish school in May with my B.S in Math and enter the workforce.  I wish I were in a position to stay in school, but I am a career changer with kids and I need money, so self learning it is!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is someing wrong in 4), just as Brian comments. Here I offered a proof for you:

> Proof: Notice that $f(x)=\frac{x} {1+x}$ is increasing on $\mathbb R^+$: to see this, let $g(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}$. It is easily to see that $g(x)$ is descreasing on $\mathbb R^+$. And note that $f(x)+g(x)=1$. Therefore, $f(x)$ is a increasing function on $\mathbb R^+$.

Since $d(x,y) \le d(x,z)+d(z,y)$, we have $d_1(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}\le{\frac{d(x,z)+d(z,y)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}}=\frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}+\frac{d(z,y)}{1+d(x,z)+d(z,y)}\lt\frac{d(x,z)}{1+d(x,z)}+\frac{d(z,y)}{1+d(z,y)}=d_1(x,z)+d_1(z,y).$

Hope this be helpful for you.

---

**ADDed:** $d(z,y)$ and $d(x,z)$ could be zero.

Comment: how does that show $\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}\le{\frac{d(x,z)+d(z,y)}{1+d(x,z)+d(y,z)}}$?  It looked trivial when I did it originally, so i offered no justification?  Is it because if $a<b$ then $\frac{1}{1+a}>\frac{1}{1+b}$?  Which, i assume by your proof, implies that $\frac{a}{1+a}<\frac{b}{1+b}$?

Comment: @CHristopher: Since $f(x)$ is a increasing function, just as i pointed out above, then $f(d(x,y))\le f(d(x,z)+d(z,y))$.

Comment: @ChristopherErnst: You are welcome.

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, you forgot that z=y. Remember, no where is it stated that each of these points are different. This will give the in equality that you are looking for.