# Real Analysis triangle inequality problems

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

$$x,y \epsilon R,\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\le\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|}$$  I have to prove this inequality.I used the triangle inequality once and have this step.  $$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|}\le\frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x+y|}$$  Now how can I prove the rest?  I don't have any idea how to use triangle inequality for the rest of the proof.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788995/proving-a-metric-with-absolute-value,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/355493/defining-a-metric-space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $f(t): t \mapsto \frac{t}{1+t}$ is increasing for $t> 0$, and so given $|x+y| \leqslant |x|+|y|$,

$$\frac{|x+y|}{1+|x+y|} \leqslant \frac{|x|+|y|}{1+|x|+|y|}= \frac{|x|}{1+|x|+|y|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|x|+|y|} \leqslant \frac{|x|}{1+|x|}+\frac{|y|}{1+|y|} $$

Equality is possible when $xy=0$.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I just looked at the chain of inequalities. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, $\frac{|x|+ |y|}{1+ |x+ y|}= \frac{|x|}{1+ |x+ y|}+ \frac{|y|}{1+ |x+ y|}$.  Now, what can you say about the relative sizes of 1+ |x+ y|  and 1+ |x| and 1+ |y|?

Comment: but we don't know that both x and y have same sign or different signs.  so i think we cant say that $1+|x+y|\gt 1+|x| or 1+|y|$